# Resetting Input field to null after clicking button in R Shiny

Tags: r, user-interface, dataframe, shiny

I am building an application in which users can enter data values for table by column. Once ADD button is clicked the entered values would be appended by column to the existing one. e.g.
if col1, 2, 3 are entered and ADD is clicked we have in the display

```
col1
   2
   3
```

and if col2, 4, 7 are entered and ADD clicked we have have the display

```
col1 col2
   2    4
   3    7
```

etc.

I would like it such that when the add button is clicked, the input fields are cleared to allow for the entry of new column. Please find below codes for the ui and server. The output table also does not display properly, any assistance to solve this problem too would be appreciated.

```
ui.R

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("My data table"),
sidebarPanel(h5("Enter input"),
           textInput("colname","Enter Column Name",NA),
           numericInput("x","X",NA),
           numericInput("y","Y",NA),
           br(),
           actionButton("Add","ADD")),
mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("out"))
))
```

And

```
server.R

shinyServer(function(input,output){

myTable <- reactive({
if(input$Add > 0)
  return(isolate({
    colnm <- input$colname
    x <- input$x
    y <-  input$y
    result <- data.frame(rbind(colnm,x,y))
    result
  }))
})

output$out <- renderTable({
myTable()
 })

})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The table needs to be rendered using `renderTable` rather then `verbatimTextOutput`. I guess you want to keep old inputs. One way to do this would be to use `reactiveValues`. EDIT: I didnt see you wanted to reset inputs. To reset inputs use the `updateNumericInput` and `updateTextInput` function. You will also need to pass a `session` variable inot your `server` function.

```
runApp(
  list(ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("My data table"),
    sidebarPanel(h5("Enter input"),
                 textInput("colname","Enter Column Name",NA),
                 numericInput("x","X",NA),
                 numericInput("y","Y",NA),
                 br(),
                 actionButton("Add","ADD")),
    mainPanel(tableOutput("out"))
  ),

  server = function(input,output,session){
    myValues <- reactiveValues()

    observe({
      if(input$Add > 0){
        isolate({
          colnm <- input$colname
          x <- input$x
          y <-  input$y
          if(!is.null(myValues$myDf)){
            myValues$myDf <- cbind(myValues$myDf, 
                                   data.frame(setNames(list(c(x, y)), colnm))
            )
          }else{
            myValues$myDf <- data.frame(setNames(list(c(x, y)), colnm))
          }

        })
        updateNumericInput(session, "x","X", NA)
        updateNumericInput(session, "y","Y", NA)
        updateTextInput(session, "colname","Enter Column Name",NA)
      }
    })

    output$out <- renderTable({
      myValues$myDf
    })

  })
)
```

EDIT:

You could change to

```
    updateNumericInput(session, "x","X", 3)
    updateNumericInput(session, "y","Y", 5)
    updateTextInput(session, "colname","Enter Column Name",'Default NAME')
```

and it works. Now the values change to default values of 3,5 and 'Default NAME'

Comment: I'm intrigued, didn't know one could run the app in a single file, good idea. I am not clear what the NAs stand for in the update numeric and text input functions. I guess this what sets the field to empty or clear the fields? Moreso, I tried to change the NAs to values other than NA but the app hangs and doesn't return the table or add the columns, please what might be responsible for that?

Comment: The NA's signify null values. You can change the numeric NA's to numeric and the Text to a character and it works.

Comment: I did change the NA values but when I click add, it doesn't bring out anything. Also, must I use the observe function? If so, why? I have been using the action button without the observe function. What exactly does it do?

Comment: Keep in mind that the change are not instantaneous: "The messages are collected and sent after all the observers (including outputs) have finished running." [https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/updateTextInput.html]